# How bind socket to device in windows?

Tags: windows, sockets, bind, device

I have same network cards in computer. All cards has identical IP. I need to bind socket to specific card. In linux I can use flag SO_BINDTODEVICE. How I can do this in windows.

P.S. This needed for UDP sockets.

Comment: How can two NICs have the same IP?

Comment: Multiple NIC with same IP is legal on seperated networks. The IP's are bound per device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a specific network interface for a socket in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065495/using-a-specific-network-interface-for-a-socket-in-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a similar question here: [Using a specific network interface for a socket in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065495/using-a-specific-network-interface-for-a-socket-in-windows/2080495#2080495)

AFIK: in Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 IP4 I believe you can't, but for IP6 you can. And for Windows Vista and Windows 2008 you can (except for certain circumstances).

Hope that helps