# How to assign the socket to particular network interface using c++ in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I need to assign the socket to a particular network interface using c++ in windows.
This link suggests that how to bind socket to a particular network interface [bind socket to network interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478167/bind-socket-to-network-interface) in linux OS but I dont know how to do it in windows using c++?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951578/how-bind-socket-to-device-in-windows